# How do I preserve search result in Django pagination

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I have develop form with Country and State field from the Profile Model. If I search for country and a particular state, I want a list of persons belonging to that country and state to display and paginated. And if the records are in multiple pages then I should be able to click on individual pages that follow to view the searched results on those pages without losing the search results.

Here is my views code with pagination.

```
def search_applicants(request):

form = ApplicantsSearchForm(request.GET or None)
if form.is_valid():
    list_submited = Profile.objects.filter(
        nation__icontains=form.cleaned_data['nation'],
        state__icontains=form.cleaned_data['state']
    )
else:
    list_submited = submited_apps.objects.all()

paginator = Paginator(list_submited, 5)
page = request.GET.get('page')
paged_listApps = paginator.get_page(page)

context = {
'list_applicants':paged_listApps,
'form':form,


}

return render(request, 'user/list_applicants.html',context)
```

I have got the pagination of all records from the Profile Model but any time I perform a search and try to click on the pagination tabs the search result is get scattered and returns to all the list items in the database.

Answer (score 0):

On the front-end you need to submit your search data when clicking on your pagination tabs as well.

Comment: Yes, I am using GET request as you can see in my views and its working. My only problem is that any time the search is done and paginated, and the user clicks on the next page, the search results get scattered

Comment: I can't tell since you haven't included the code for the font-end, but my guess is your GET request is missing the `nation` and `state` attributes when you make the paginated request. You need to include those, otherwise `form.is_valid()` will evaluate to `False` and you will get anunfiltered queryset

Comment: has this been solved? im looking for a way to paginate search results as well, every time i click on the next page it reverts to its non-filtered form